# how to write a function that checks if two classes are the same

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a memory game using JS. I've managed to get some toggling working that changes the class back and forth between the two card faces. I'm trying to get a function down now that checks if two game cards are matched, if they are the images stay flipped, if they're not the images revert back to the card face.

```
// variable declarations for game elements
let gameTiles = document.getElementsByClassName('game_tile');
let cardFace = document.getElementsByClassName('card_face');
let cardMatchCheck = [];
let cardArray = 
[ "one", "one", "two", "two", "three", "three", 
 "four", "four", "five", "five", "six", "six", 
"seven", "seven", "eight", "eight", "nine", "nine", 
 "ten", "ten", "eleven", "eleven", "twelve", "twelve" ];

// div class assignment for loop from the cardArray
// .className += allows for adding to an already assigned class
// in this case "game_tile" (our button class)

for (let i = 0; i < gameTiles.length; i++) {
for (let j = 0; j < cardArray.length; j++) {
    gameTiles[i].setAttribute("class", cardArray[j]);
   } 
} 

// click response (working)
let gameTileClick = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
for (let i = 0; i < gameTileClick.length; i++) {
    gameTileClick[i].addEventListener('click', changeCardImage);
}

  // testing grounds:

// this function runs through all card classes, and switches 
// between both card image states (back, front, back)
// need to work on implementing the pair recognition

function changeCardImage(cardArray) {
if (cardArray.className == 'one') {
    cardArray.className = 'card_one_img'
    cardMatchCheck.push(cardArray.className);
    cardMatch();
    cardMismatch();
} else if (cardArray.className == 'card_one_img') {
    cardArray.className = "one"    
} else if (cardArray.className == 'two') {
    cardArray.className = 'card_two_img'
    cardMatchCheck.push(cardArray.className);
    cardMatch();
    cardMismatch();
} else if (cardArray.className == 'card_two_img') {
    cardArray.className = 'two'
} else if (cardArray.className == 'three') {
    cardArray.className = 'card_three_img'
} else if (cardArray.className == 'card_three_img') {
    cardArray.className = 'three'
} else if (cardArray.className == 'four') {
    cardArray.className = 'card_four_img'
} else if (cardArray.className == 'card_four_img') {
    cardArray.className = 'four'
} else if (cardArray.className == 'five') {
    cardArray.className = 'card_five_img'
} else if (cardArray.className == 'card_five_img') {
    cardArray.className = 'five'
} else if (cardArray.className == 'six') {
    cardArray.className = 'card_six_img'
} else if (cardArray.className == 'card_six_img') {
    cardArray.className = 'six'
} else if (cardArray.className == 'seven') {
    cardArray.className = 'card_seven_img'
} else if (cardArray.className == 'card_seven_img') {
    cardArray.className = 'seven'
}  else if (cardArray.className == 'eight') {
    cardArray.className = 'card_eight_img'
} else if (cardArray.className == 'card_eight_img') {
    cardArray.className = 'eight'
}  else if (cardArray.className == 'nine') {
    cardArray.className = 'card_nine_img'
} else if (cardArray.className == 'card_nine_img') {
    cardArray.className = 'nine'
}  else if (cardArray.className == 'ten') {
    cardArray.className = 'card_ten_img'
} else if (cardArray.className == 'card_ten_img') {
    cardArray.className = 'ten'
}  else if (cardArray.className == 'eleven') {
    cardArray.className = 'card_eleven_img'
} else if (cardArray.className == 'card_eleven_img') {
    cardArray.className = 'eleven'
}  else if (cardArray.className == 'twelve') {
    cardArray.className = 'card_twelve_img'
} else if (cardArray.className == 'card_twelve_img') {
    cardArray.className = 'twelve'
    } 
}

console.log(cardMatchCheck);


// function for checking card match/mismatch 

function cardMatch() {
if (cardArray.className == cardArray.className) {
    console.log('match');
    }         
}   

function cardMismatch() {
if (cardArray.className != cardArray.className) {
    cardArray.className = 'card_face';
    }
}
```

Apologies if any formatting is funky - this is my first SO post. Any direction is much appreciated. Thank you in advance for your time!

Edit: here's what I have so far: https://codepen.io/woolsox/pen/mMRPJK

Comment: What's your question?

Please put the code on http://codepen.io so people can see what it does.

Comment: sorry about that - just added the codepen. I'm trying to figure out how to write a function that allows the game to recognize when two cards are the same they stay revealed, and if not, they flip back.

Comment: This entire approach is error prone and has lots of unnecessary duplicate code. You should use an array to store the cards, and use a negative value to indicate that a card was flipped. This will reduce those `else if`s to two or three lines total, and allow you to add more images at any point without adding more copy-pasta code.

Comment: It should be a **pure function** to check that..

Comment: SO is not a free code writing service. Questions should identify a specific issue with sufficient (minimal) code in the question (not posted elsewhere) to replicate the issue. It should also include input, expected and actual output along with any errors.

Comment: @RobG got it - new to code, new to SO. wasn't looking for someone to write me an answer, but rather for some help in trying to get started in the right direction. sorry if the code was lengthy - but i thought it'd be best to post all of it to make sense of the whole program. your points are noted and will be kept in mind for future submissions. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Some thoughts:

1) It seems like your if else logic can be reduced to:

```
 var tmp= cardArray.className.split("_");
 cardArray.className = tmp.length>1?tmp[1]:"card_"+tmp[0]+"_img";
```

2)Simply keep a pointer of the previous element:

```
var before = null;
function cardClicked(){
   if(before){
    if(before.className === this.className){
      alert("match");
    }
     before = null;
  }else{
     before = this;
  }
 }
```

Comment: i'm very new to JS - can you explain some of this? thanks for taking the time to reply.

Comment: @woolsox could you describe which part of it? I mean the code does what it says

Comment: by setting before to null, what exactly are you accomplishing? and this.className - what is "this" doing? i'm not completely clear on their usage. thank you Jonas.

Comment: @woolsox 1) that *hides* the first opened card. If not clicking the third time could match the second click. 2) thats the called context, if you do document.getElementById("sth").onclick = cardClicked; this will be sth

Comment: You could also use a scheme using say "one" and "one_invert", then just add or remove the "_invert" part as required.

Comment: @RobG this is a good idea, as I got further into this (and realized what I needed next) I was thinking redoing the naming scheme would be helpful, thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, just a suggestion.

Elements have a [*classList*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) property with a *toggle* method. In your case, you can apply a default styling to an element, then change its appearance by toggling a class on or off in the same way you're swapping between 'card_ten_img' and 'ten'. You can also use event delegation and only add one listener to the document, which sees if a click comes from a card and behaves accordingly. E.g.

```js
// If event target has class .card, toggle inverted class
function invertCard(evt) {
  var el = evt.target;
  if (el.classList.contains('card')) {
    el.classList.toggle('inverted');
   }
}

// Add listener to document to handle clicks on cards
document.body.addEventListener('click', invertCard, false);
```

```css
/* Default style for a card */
.card {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
}

/* Additional style for inverted card */
.inverted {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">A</div>
<div class="card">B</div>
<div class="card">C</div>
```

You may want to use a more general *handleClick* function that sees where the click came from and implements logic based on the source, its current state, game state and the rules of the game.

Comment: Note that clicking on inner elements of the card wouldnt trigger the card change.